# ERROR: LNK 2019 : unresolved external symbol _imp_CrtDbgReportw in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012

I have written a program that splits a string when the respective delimiter occurs. But a different error is occurring like :

> ```
> Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___CrtDbgReportW referenced in function "public: char const & __thiscall std::_String_const_iterator<class std::_String_val<struct std::_Simple_types<char> > >::operator*(void)const " (??D?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@QBEABDXZ)    Source.cpp Using Object_Type Input
> ```

I tested the same program in **dev c++** and it is working fine but in visual studio these type of problems are raising.

**My Program:**

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include<tchar.h>
using namespace std;

 #pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

string s = "Enter a line of text,\n next line\n as the\n delimiter: ";
string delimiter = "\n";
size_t pos = 0;
string token;

while ((pos = s.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos) {
    token = s.substr(0, pos);
    std::cout << token << std::endl;
    s.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
}
std::cout << s << std::endl;

return 0;

}
```

I even tried removing the header  and changing the main() function to int main() and int main(void). But the same error occurs in visual studio. Please anyone help me.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`CrtDbgReport` is defined in debug version of [CRT (C Run-time Library)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/abx4dbyh). You are most likely building debug configuration but linking against release version of CRT.

Check Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime library.

Other possibility is that you are building release configuration but have some define that is causing `string` to be built in debug configuration. The easiest example of this would be:

```
#define _DEBUG
#include <string>
```

and building your example in release will cause exactly this problem even if the correct runtime library is chosen.

Comment: Thanks. I changed my run time library to MTd. It worked.

Comment: Changing my runtime lib to MTd worked for me too. Thanks to both of you.