# Strange error thrown when creating a string in c++

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and trying to create a string.

When I add this line: `std::string log;` I get the following error. Any ideas?

> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReport referenced in function "void * __cdecl std::_Allocate_manually_vector_aligned<struct std::_Default_allocate_traits>(unsigned int)" (??$_Allocate_manually_vector_aligned@U_Default_allocate_traits@std@@@std@@YAPAXI@Z)    *proj Name* *.obj   1

Comment: I think your installation is messed up. That looks like a CRT version problem. Try reinstalling visual studio and/or windows SDK.

Comment: Maybe not quite as serious as I first suggested, it could just be your project settings messed up somehow, see here for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42801276/error-lnk-2019-unresolved-external-symbol-imp-crtdbgreportw-in-visual-studio

Comment: What does your environment look like?

Comment: please show a [mre]