# Plenty of errors that appeared after changing main() to WinMain() in order to draw a simple window

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm creating a simple WinAPI window, but there are plenty of errors that appeared. How can I fix them?

```
1>MSVCRTD.lib(init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReport referenced in function __CRT_RTC_INIT
1>MSVCRTD.lib(init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW referenced in function __CRT_RTC_INITW
1>MSVCRTD.lib(error.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _strcpy_s referenced in function "void __cdecl _RTC_StackFailure(void *,char const *)" (?_RTC_StackFailure@@YAXPAXPBD@Z)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(error.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _strcat_s referenced in function "void __cdecl _RTC_StackFailure(void *,char const *)" (?_RTC_StackFailure@@YAXPAXPBD@Z)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(error.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___stdio_common_vsprintf_s referenced in function __vsprintf_s_l
1>MSVCRTD.lib(pdblkup.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __wmakepath_s referenced in function "int __cdecl GetPdbDllPathFromFilePath(wchar_t const *,wchar_t *,unsigned int)" (?GetPdbDllPathFromFilePath@@YAHPB_WPA_WI@Z)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(pdblkup.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __wsplitpath_s referenced in function "int __cdecl GetPdbDllPathFromFilePath(wchar_t const *,wchar_t *,unsigned int)" (?GetPdbDllPathFromFilePath@@YAHPB_WPA_WI@Z)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(pdblkup.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _wcscpy_s referenced in function "int __cdecl GetPdbDllPathFromFilePath(wchar_t const *,wchar_t *,unsigned int)" (?GetPdbDllPathFromFilePath@@YAHPB_WPA_WI@Z)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(pdblkup.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___vcrt_GetModuleFileNameW referenced in function "struct HINSTANCE__ * __cdecl GetPdbDll(void)" (?GetPdbDll@@YAPAUHINSTANCE__@@XZ)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(pdblkup.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___vcrt_GetModuleHandleW referenced in function "struct HINSTANCE__ * __cdecl GetPdbDll(void)" (?GetPdbDll@@YAPAUHINSTANCE__@@XZ)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(pdblkup.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___vcrt_LoadLibraryExW referenced in function "struct HINSTANCE__ * __cdecl GetPdbDll(void)" (?GetPdbDll@@YAPAUHINSTANCE__@@XZ)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(chandler4_noexcept.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _terminate referenced in function __except_handler4_noexcept
1>MSVCRTD.lib(chandler4_noexcept.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___current_exception referenced in function __except_handler4_noexcept
1>MSVCRTD.lib(chandler4_noexcept.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___current_exception_context referenced in function __except_handler4_noexcept
1>MSVCRTD.lib(chandler4gs.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __except_handler4_common referenced in function __except_handler4
```

```
#include <Windows.h>

#pragma comment(linker, "/ENTRY:WinMain")
#pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS")

const wchar_t g_szClassName[] = L"myWindowClass";

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG Msg;

    //Step 1: Registering the Window Class
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEXW);
    wc.style = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIconW(nullptr, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursorW(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = reinterpret_cast<HBRUSH>(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wc.lpszMenuName = nullptr;
    wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIconW(nullptr, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if (!RegisterClassExW(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Window Registration Failed!", L"Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    // Step 2: Creating the Window
    hwnd = CreateWindowExW(
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        g_szClassName,
        L"The title of my window",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 240, 120,
        NULL, nullptr, hInstance, NULL);

    if (!hwnd)
    {
        MessageBoxW(nullptr, L"Window Creation Failed!", L"Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    // Step 3: The Message Loop
    while (GetMessageW(&Msg, nullptr, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&Msg);
    }
    return Msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42801276/error-lnk-2019-unresolved-external-symbol-imp-crtdbgreportw-in-visual-studio) answer your question?

Comment: @DrewDormann, I tried changing it to /MTd, but it didn't work.

Comment: When I compile in Release mode, it works, why it doesn't work in Debug?

Comment: take any unresolved symbol, `___vcrt_GetModuleHandleW` for instance. go to the lib folders - and search for it. and you found that it in `vcruntime.lib`. are `vcruntime.lib` included to lib files ? no ? add it. still exist errors ? take another symbol and search - in which lib it located

Comment: @RbMm, where can I find the lib folder?

Comment: `__except_handler4` - *libucrt.lib* and usually this 2 libs

Comment: @nop - but where linker can find the lib folder? why you want from linker found this if you can not ? look for your folder settings in msvc

Comment: @RbMm, Additional Dependencies: `kernel32.lib;user32.lib;gdi32.lib;winspool.lib;comdlg32.lib;advapi32.lib;shell32.lib;ole32.lib;oleaut32.lib;uuid.lib;odbc32.lib;odbccp32.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)`

Comment: add *vcruntimed.lib* and *libucrtd.lib*

Comment: @RbMm, `1>libucrtd.lib(environment_initialization.obj) : error LNK2005: __initialize_narrow_environment already defined in ucrtd.lib(ucrtbased.dll)` after I added them.

Comment: you need use only one from this lib - this is mutually - or *libucrtd.lib* (static link functions) or *ucrtd.lib* - forward to *ucrtbased.dll*

Comment: @SimonMourier, deleted them and still the same.

Comment: @RbMm, I think the problem is in the code. I tried pasting the same code into a new project, it still didn't work out.

Comment: @nop - problem when no understanding how linker search for symbols. i describe how in general resolve this - search manually, where some symbol defined and add this lib

Comment: delete the #pragma comment(linker, "/ENTRY:WinMain") line

Comment: @SimonMourier, still the same. You can try pasting the code into a VS 2019 project

Comment: more correct #pragma comment(linker, "/ENTRY:WinMainCRTStartup")

Comment: Works fine for me with this line removed.

Comment: @RbMm, is this the lib folder: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x86`?

Comment: this is sdk folder, *ucrt\x86* too. also exist msvc folder. if want deep understand - set option - */NODEFAULTLIB* and add to linker input *vcruntime.lib;msvcrt.lib;ucrt.lib* - what will be result ?

Comment: There's no way for us to repro the issue. Please show a [mcve] including the command line used to compile and link the program.

Comment: I understand what the problem was. I copied that example code from http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/simple_window.html and it looks like the encoding was being broken. Did some Ctrl + A & Ctrl + C & Ctrl + V a few times and now it works, thank you very much, everyone!

Comment: Honestly, that's about as likely as getting hit by lightning and winning the jackpot of the national lottery. On the same day. If there were some sort of encoding issue, your compiler would have complained. But it didn't and instead successfully ran to completion.

Comment: @IInspectable, after the latest VS update, it's struggling with it. Even on C#.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, sorry. And C# uses a **vastly** different build model compared to C++, so I'm not sure what point you are trying to make.

Comment: @IInspectable, the point is Microsoft broke something in VS after the latest update, at least for me, or it's ReSharper mocking it.

Comment: Rule #1 in programming: The issue is in your code. There's absolutely **no** evidence that there were an issue with the IDE. The compiler works, and the linker complains about missing symbols *you* failed to make available. Sounds like a fully functioning build environment to me.